# Uploading zip file to Elementor in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to upload a zip file with 201 files which are page sections for Elementor. I can do it one file at a time if I extract the zip file but WP should be able to extract and install them all at once from the zip file. Tried Googling it but most of the answers pertain to upping the PHP max post size. This is set at 8M and the zip file is 373K. If I upload it from within Elementor it seems to hang and if I upload it through my templates it quickly refreshes and shows the same templates that were already there. Here is my system info:

```
== Server Environment ==
    Operating System: Linux
    Software: Apache
    MySQL version: 5.5.56
    PHP Version: 7.2.8
    PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
    PHP Max Post Size: 8M
    GD Installed: Yes
    ZIP Installed: Yes
    Write Permissions: All right
    Elementor Library: Connected

== WordPress Environment ==
    Version: 4.9.7
    Site URL: http://stevenbuick.co.uk/wordpress
    Home URL: http://stevenbuick.co.uk/wordpress
    WP Multisite: No
    Max Upload Size: 4 MB
    Memory limit: 64M
    Permalink Structure: /%postname%/
    Language: en-US
    Timezone: 0
    Debug Mode: Inactive

== Theme ==
    Name: OceanWP
    Version: 1.5.21
    Author: Nick
    Child Theme: No

== User ==
    Role: administrator
    WP Profile lang: en_US
    User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36

== Active Plugins ==
    Elementor
        Version: 2.1.6
        Author: Elementor.com

    Ocean Demo Import
        Version: 1.0.9
        Author: OceanWP

    Ocean Extra
        Version: 1.4.19
        Author: OceanWP


== Debug ==
    Errors: There are no errors to display
```

I've tried disabling all the other plugins but still no joy.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this might be an issue with nested directories. What is the structure of the zip file? Are any files in sub folders? Try uploading the archive with all 201 files in root of the archive (no sub folders).

Comment: Working now! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

go to cpanel wp-config.php file and paste define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','256M'); this line  bellow to define('WP_DEBUG', false);
and the upload zip file, it works.